# Distribution of malware obfuscation types

Tags: malware, obfuscation

There are several statistics and numbers out there of current malware families and their distributions.

However, I'am looking for statistics which shows the distribution of **malware** differed by their **obfuscation types**, i.e. current distribution of `encrypted`, `oligomorphic`, `polymorphic`, `metamorphic` in the wild.

So far I mainly focused reports lastly published by AV vendors, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems so that there are no existing publications/statistics from av vendors. Reffered to [A] and the mentioned entropy analysis, 90% of the used samples are obfuscated by a polymorphic technique.

> **[A] Toward Generic Unpacking Techniques for Malware Analysis with**
>   **Quantification of Code Revelation** - 2009

Perhaps a own analysis could help with a bigger set of malware samples. The following "evalualtion" of me was done with the public available [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/malware-classification/data) malware set. Even if it is not a clear classifcation of the used obfuscation technique of the families, hopefully this approach could help you out or point you to the right direction. 
I did the classifaction with the help of different statistics like entropy value, chi-square distribution and a pi approximation.

```
NORM    COMPR   ENCR
-----------------------------------------
581     691     260      Ramnit      
2475    3       0        Lollipop 
0       10      2932     Kelihos_ver3    
6       51      418      Vundo   
3       22      18       Simda  
233     260     258      Tracur   
387     4       7        Kelihos_ver1 
524     667     37       Obfuscator  
779     219     15       Gatak  

NORM  = non-obfuscated characteristics (i.e. not compressed/encrypted)
COMPR = compressed or packed characteristics
ENCR  = encrypted characteristics
```

Comment: Even it is not the perfect and preferred answer  it encoureges me to do an own analysis  thank you